# Portable Area not finding embedded files MVC4 C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, portable-areas

I have a solution with two projects in it. A portable areas project, and a web site that references the portable areas project, and Both reference MvcContrib.

The problem I am have is with the embedded resources, they are giving me a 404 error when I try to get to them. It seems like it's trying to access a physical path not the dll. The partial view works fine.

The file I'm trying to access looks like this inside my visual studio solution explorer

AdHocReporting/Areas/AdHocReportBuilder/Content/adhoc.css (the build action is embedded)

**Here is the routing for the portable area:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcContrib.PortableAreas;

namespace AdHocReporting.Areas.AdHocReportBuilder
{
    public class AdHocReportBuilderAreaRegistration : PortableAreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "AdHocReportBuilder"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context, IApplicationBus bus)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(context);
            RegisterAreaEmbeddedResources();

        }
        private void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
              AreaName + "_content",
              base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/Content/{resourceName}",
              new { controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index", resourcePath = "Content" },
              new[] { "MvcContrib.PortableAreas" }
          );

            context.MapRoute(
                AreaName + "_default",
                base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Web sites Global.aspx that has the reference to the portable area**

```
namespace AdHocReportingSite
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            PortableAreaRegistration.RegisterEmbeddedViewEngine();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

**here is an image of what my solution explore looks like:**

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: Silly question, but do your embedded resources have their Build Action set to "Embedded Resource"?

Comment: Yes, they do. I'm not sure what the issue was so I rebuilt the whole project from scratch and it ended up working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not reproduce the issue once I created a new project and redid everything. I'm not sure if it was an error or I just missed a step in setting up my portable areas.

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.Config add for each file type:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="js" path="*.js" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This will make IIS try to use the defined routes instead of searching for the static file.

Comment: nice, I'll remember that next time. I'm done working with this model for now. Thanks