# How to set up MVC portable areas to use resources from a complex directory structure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing, mvccontrib

I'm using portable areas in an MVC 2 application. I have a javascript file in a folder
/Scripts/ViewModels/ViewModel.js but when I try to access it, I get a 404 error for not found. The registration for the portable area looks like this:

```
private void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
          AreaName + "_resources",
          base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/resource/{resourceName}",
          new { controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index"},
          new[] { "MvcContrib.PortableAreas" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
          AreaName + "_scripts",
          base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/Scripts/{resourceName}",
          new { controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index", resourcePath = "scripts" },
          new[] { "MvcContrib.PortableAreas" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            AreaName + "_images",
            base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/images/{resourceName}",
            new { controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index", resourcePath = "images" },
            new[] { "MvcContrib.PortableAreas" }
       );

        context.MapRoute(
            AreaName + "_default",
            base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "PortableAreaDemo.PortableAreas.Areas.Demo.Controllers", "MvcContrib" }
        );
    }
```

In a view template I tried to include the scripts file with 
`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Demo/Scripts/ViewModels/ViewModel.js")"></script>`
and I get the following url `/Demo/Scripts/ViewModels/ViewModel.js` but the file is not accessable. I can only access script files which are direct children of the Scripts folder.

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.  You suggest you are trying to load a file from `/Scripts/ViewModels/ViewModel.js` but you then state that the url `/Demo/Scripts/ViewModels/ViewModel.js` doesn't work.  do you need the `/Demo/` folder in the path or not?

Comment: @Andrew: I do need the Demo in the path but that's not a folder but the name of the area. Problem is that the files from /Demo/Scripts/ViewModels/ folder are not loaded. If I put the file in the Scripts folder then it's fine. So for example /Demo/Scripts/ViewModel.js is loaded correctly.

Comment: ok I apologize, I obviously misunderstood your question... so your issue isn't with the area, it's with accessing files from a sub-folder of the scripts folder.

Answer (score 2):

from the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) on routing,

> Sometimes you have to handle URL requests that contain a variable number of URL segments. When you define a route, you can specify that if a URL has more segments than there are in the pattern, the extra segments are considered to be part of the last segment. To handle additional segments in this manner you mark the last parameter with an asterisk (*). This is referred to as a catch-all parameter. A route with a catch-all parameter will also match URLs that do not contain any values for the last parameter.

so, you should try adding an `*` to the beginning of the argument for your scripts path, eg, `base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/Scripts/{*resourceName}",` which would allow for the parameter to be handled as a catch-all.  The `resourceName` would then be able to be assigned to either `/ViewModel.js` or `/ViewModels/ViewModel.js`.  without the `*`, the `/ViewModels` segment is treated as another segment, which causes the Routing Engine to not evaluate this route as a match, and continue through the defined routes, and the `404` is a result of no routes matching the pattern of the URL path provided.

Comment: I feel like the best answer is don't use Portable Areas. But otherwise, this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following route [must be inserted before the "/Scripts/{resourceName}" route]

```
context.MapRoute(
      AreaName + "_viewmodels_scripts",
      base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/Scripts/viewmodels/{resourceName}",
      new { controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index", resourcePath =     "scripts.viewmodels" },
      new[] { "MvcContrib.PortableAreas" }
    );
```

and don't forget to set the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" for your scripts

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695580/portable-area-not-finding-embedded-files-mvc4-c-sharp/25815489#25815489)

In the Web.Config add for each file type:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="js" path="*.js" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This will make IIS try to use the defined routes instead of searching for the static file.