# Cannot access the portable area controllers from webforms solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a webforms website which runs both webforms and MVC 4.0. I have created a MVC Portable Area by following the steps in [this article](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/06/mvc-portable-areas/), and I am trying to implement it into my webforms solution by using **MvcContrib** from nuget.

I have added a **Areas** folder in my webforms solutions which holds the web.config file from the portable areas/view folder. Futhermore I have added a reference to the portable area in my main webforms project. I have also changed all my views in my portable area to be build as EmbeddedResources.

However when I try to access my portable area controller in the browser I get an error. 
It seems that my webforms solution cannot find the portable area controllers / views, as it searches in my webforms solution for the view and not my portable area.

My AreaRegistration class in my portable area looks like this:

```
public class DemoAreaRegistration : PortableAreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Demo"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context, IApplicationBus bus)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(context);
        bus.Send(new PortableAreaStartupMessage("Registering PortableArea Area"));
        RegisterAreaEmbeddedResources();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            AreaName + "_scripts",
            base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/Scripts/{resourceName}",
            new {controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index", resourcePath = "scripts"},
            new[] {"MvcContrib.PortableAreas"}
            );

        context.MapRoute(
            AreaName + "_images",
            base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/images/{resourceName}",
            new {controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index", resourcePath = "images"},
            new[] {"MvcContrib.PortableAreas"}
            );

        context.MapRoute(
            AreaName + "_default",
            base.AreaRoutePrefix + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            new[] {"PortableArea.Areas.Demo.Controllers", "MvcContrib"}
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695580/portable-area-not-finding-embedded-files-mvc4-c-sharp/25815489#25815489)

In the Web.Config add for each file type:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="js" path="*.js" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This will make IIS try to use the defined routes instead of searching for the static file.